# Putting margins between Buttons

Tags: html, css, button, margins

I want to put margins/spacing between each of these four `Buttons`. I am struggling a bit with the css. The following code does not give me space between each `Button`. Does anyone know what I need to change?

practice.html

```
<div>
    <input type="button" id="button0" style="color:black; width:100px; height: 50px" />    
    <input type="button" id="button1" style="color:black; width:100px; height: 50px"  />
    <input type="button" id="button2" style="color:black; width:100px; height: 50px"  />    
    <input type="button" id="button3" style="color:black; width:100px; height: 50px" />
</div>
```

practice.css

```
.button{
    margin: 20px;
}
```

Comment: just remove the dot from `.button{}` instead write `button{ margin: 20px;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add class="button" for each button:

```
<input class="button" type="button" id="button0" style="color:black; width:100px; height: 50px" />
```

Comment: not working for some reason. would the above code not work if the buttons are wrapped in a div?

Comment: does it work when you put margin:20px inside the input element? i.e:     <input type="button" id="button1" style="color:black; width:100px; height: 50px; margin: 20px"  />

Comment: yes. do you know why it works like that and not in the css file?

Comment: add this to your under <head> element: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="practice.css">

Answer (score 3):

.button is responsible for class. You should write

```
button {margin: 20px;}
```

Thats all :). Remember that button should have display: block or display: inline-block, so the element can render margin property properly.

---

Example of different CSS selectors:

```
button {} // <button>
.buttonclass {} // <button class="buttonclass">
#buttonid {} // <button id="buttonid">
```

Answer (score 1):

`.button` is a class selector and you have no classes set. `button` as a selector won't work with the given HTML as the element is `input`. The correct css would be

```
input[type="button"]
{
    margin:20px;
}
```

```css
input[type="button"] {
  color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="button" id="button0" />

  <input type="button" id="button1" />
  <input type="button" id="button2" />

  <input type="button" id="button3" />
</div>
```

From your comments it sounds like there is another style being applied from somewhere. You may need to make a more [specific](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) selector.

Try

```
div input[type="button"]
{
    margin:20px;
}
```

Also use Chrome Developer tools or Firebug for Firefox to inspect the buttons to see what styes are being applied to your buttons. Don't forget to flush your cache as well (ctr +f5) as CSS is cached by the browser.

More info on getting started with [CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)

Comment: not working. Do I need to change something if these 4 buttons are wrapped in a <div> ?

Comment: No, if it is not working there is some other style that is overriding the style. Use Chrome Developer tools to inspect the buttons and see what styles are being applied. I've updated the snippet in wo wrap the buttons in a div to demonstrate.